# bundle install always in Resolving dependencies progress

Tags: ruby, bundle, fastlane

when I am using this command in macOS Catalina 10.15:

```
bundle install --verbose
```

shows this log output is:

```
$ bundle install --verbose
Running `bundle install --verbose` with bundler 2.2.3
Found changes from the lockfile, re-resolving dependencies because the list of sources changed, the dependencies in your gemfile changed, you added a new platform to your gemfile
HTTP GET https://gems.ruby-china.com/versions
HTTP 304 Not Modified https://gems.ruby-china.com/versions
Fetching gem metadata from https://gems.ruby-china.com/
Looking up gems ["xcode-install", "fastlane", "fastlane-plugin-pgyer"]
Looking up gems ["claide", "fastlane_core", "nokogiri", "spaceship", "capybara", "colored", "commander", "deliver", "highline", "json", "poltergeist", "security", "credentials_manager", "frameit", "pem", "shenzhen", "sigh", "snapshot", "produce", "slack-notifier", "hipchat", "cert", "aws-sdk", "xcodeproj", "terminal-notifier", "xcpretty", "cupertino", "terminal-table", "krausefx-shenzhen", "pbxplorer", "rest-client", "gym", "pilot", "plist", "addressable", "artifactory", "slather", "scan", "supply", "match", "screengrab", "multipart-post", "word_wrap", "bundler", "activesupport", "babosa", "dotenv", "excon", "faraday", "faraday-cookie_jar", "faraday_middleware", "fastimage", "gh_inspector", "google-api-client", "mini_magick", "multi_json", "multi_xml", "rubyzip", "xcpretty-travis-formatter", "colored2", "tty-screen", "commander-fastlane", "CFPropertyList", "public_suffix", "tty-spinner", "simctl", "emoji_regex", "bootsnap", "google-cloud-storage", "jwt", "aws-sdk-s3", "naturally"]
Looking up gems ["hoe", "weakling", "mini_portile", "mini_portile2", "pkg-config", "racc", "termios", "culerity", "database_cleaner", "rack", "selenium-webdriver", "rack-test", "mime-types", "celerity", "xpath", "mini_mime", "regexp_parser", "uglifier", "prawn", "phantomjs", "httparty", "mimemagic", "rake", "nanaimo", "atomos", "pry", "cookiejar", "sentry-raven", "em-websocket", "sfl", "faye-websocket", "http_parser.rb", "childprocess", "cliver", "websocket-driver", "net-sftp", "unicode-display_width", "uuidtools", "aws-sdk-v1", "aws-sdk-resources", "aws-sdk-acm", "aws-sdk-apigateway", "aws-sdk-applicationautoscaling", "aws-sdk-applicationdiscoveryservice", "aws-sdk-autoscaling", "aws-sdk-budgets", "aws-sdk-cloudformation", "aws-sdk-cloudfront", "aws-sdk-cloudhsm", "aws-sdk-cloudsearch", "aws-sdk-cloudsearchdomain", "aws-sdk-cloudtrail", "aws-sdk-cloudwatch", "aws-sdk-cloudwatchevents", "aws-sdk-cloudwatchlogs", "aws-sdk-codecommit", "aws-sdk-codedeploy", "aws-sdk-codepipeline", "aws-sdk-cognitoidentity", "aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider", "aws-sdk-cognitosync", "aws-sdk-configservice", "aws-sdk-databasemigrationservice", "aws-sdk-datapipeline", "aws-sdk-devicefarm", "aws-sdk-directconnect", "aws-sdk-directoryservice", "aws-sdk-dynamodb", "aws-sdk-dynamodbstreams", "aws-sdk-ec2", "aws-sdk-ecr", "aws-sdk-ecs", "aws-sdk-efs", "aws-sdk-elasticache", "aws-sdk-elasticbeanstalk", "aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancing", "aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2", "aws-sdk-elasticsearchservice", "aws-sdk-elastictranscoder", "aws-sdk-emr", "aws-sdk-firehose", "aws-sdk-gamelift", "aws-sdk-glacier", "aws-sdk-iam", "aws-sdk-importexport", "aws-sdk-inspector", "aws-sdk-iot", "aws-sdk-iotdataplane", "aws-sdk-kinesis", "aws-sdk-kinesisanalytics", "aws-sdk-kms", "aws-sdk-lambda", "aws-sdk-lambdapreview", "aws-sdk-machinelearning", "aws-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics", "aws-sdk-marketplacemetering", "aws-sdk-opsworks", "aws-sdk-rds", "aws-sdk-redshift", "aws-sdk-route53", "aws-sdk-route53domains", "aws-sdk-servicecatalog", "aws-sdk-ses", "aws-sdk-simpledb", "aws-sdk-sms", "aws-sdk-snowball", "aws-sdk-sns", "aws-sdk-sqs", "aws-sdk-ssm", "aws-sdk-storagegateway", "aws-sdk-support", "aws-sdk-swf", "aws-sdk-waf", "aws-sdk-workspaces", "aws-sdk-appstream", "aws-sdk-codebuild", "aws-sdk-health", "aws-sdk-lightsail", "aws-sdk-opsworkscm", "aws-sdk-pinpoint", "aws-sdk-polly", "aws-sdk-rekognition", "aws-sdk-sfn", "aws-sdk-shield", "aws-sdk-wafregional", "aws-sdk-xray", "aws-sdk-batch", "aws-sdk-clouddirectory", "aws-sdk-costandusagereportservice", "aws-sdk-lexruntimeservice", "aws-sdk-mturk", "aws-sdk-organizations", "aws-sdk-workdocs", "aws-sdk-codestar", "aws-sdk-lexmodelbuildingservice", "aws-sdk-resourcegroupstaggingapi", "aws-sdk-lex", "aws-sdk-marketplaceentitlementservice", "aws-sdk-states", "aws-sdk-athena", "paint", "rouge", "rspec", "httpclient", "i18n", "mechanize", "term-ansicolor", "netrc", "certified", "rdoc", "ffi", "http-cookie", "http-accept", "builder", "memcache-client", "tzinfo", "minitest", "thread_safe", "concurrent-ruby", "method_source", "zeitwerk", "clamp", "extlib", "httpadapter", "signet", "launchy", "liquid", "sinatra", "autoparse", "retriable", "googleauth", "hurley", "memoist", "representable", "thor", "virtus", "rexml", "google-apis-core", "google-apis-generator", "hashie", "oauth2", "roauth", "dotenv-deployment", "subexec", "ruby2_keywords", "faraday-net_http", "tty-cursor", "digest-crc", "google-cloud-core", "google-apis-iamcredentials_v1", "google-apis-storage_v1", "libxml-ruby", "aws-sdk-core", "aws-sigv4", "msgpack", "snappy"]
Looking up gems ["rubyforge", "RubyInline", "gemcutter", "mime-types-data", "cucumber", "therubyracer", "execjs", "prawn-layout", "prawn-core", "prawn-format", "prawn-security", "pdf-reader", "ttfunk", "afm", "ruby-rc4", "pdf-core", "jnunemaker-crack", "crack", "json_pure", "libwebsocket", "websocket", "database_cleaner-active_record", "eventmachine", "websocket-extensions", "ruby_parser", "coderay", "win32console", "yard", "slop", "spoon", "yajl-ruby", "certifi", "net-ssh", "thin", "aws-sdk-dax", "aws-sdk-greengrass", "aws-sdk-cloudhsmv2", "aws-sdk-glue", "aws-sdk-migrationhub", "aws-sdk-mobile", "aws-sdk-pricing", "aws-sdk-costexplorer", "aws-sdk-mediaconvert", "aws-sdk-medialive", "aws-sdk-mediapackage", "aws-sdk-mediastore", "aws-sdk-mediastoredata", "aws-sdk-appsync", "aws-sdk-guardduty", "aws-sdk-mq", "aws-sdk-comprehend", "aws-sdk-iotjobsdataplane", "aws-sdk-kinesisvideo", "aws-sdk-kinesisvideoarchivedmedia", "aws-sdk-kinesisvideomedia", "aws-sdk-sagemaker", "aws-sdk-sagemakerruntime", "aws-sdk-translate", "aws-sdk-resourcegroups", "aws-sdk-alexaforbusiness", "aws-sdk-cloud9", "aws-sdk-serverlessapplicationrepository", "aws-sdk-servicediscovery", "aws-sdk-workmail", "aws-sdk-autoscalingplans", "aws-sdk-transcribeservice", "aws-sdk-connect", "aws-sdk-acmpca", "aws-sdk-fms", "aws-sdk-secretsmanager", "aws-sdk-iotanalytics", "aws-sdk-iot1clickdevicesservice", "aws-sdk-iot1clickprojects", "aws-sdk-pi", "aws-sdk-neptune", "aws-sdk-mediatailor", "aws-sdk-eks", "aws-sdk-macie", "aws-sdk-dlm", "aws-sdk-signer", "aws-sdk-chime", "aws-sdk-pinpointemail", "aws-sdk-pinpointsmsvoice", "aws-sdk-ram", "aws-sdk-route53resolver", "aws-sdk-s3control", "aws-sdk-quicksight", "aws-sdk-rdsdataservice", "aws-sdk-amplify", "aws-sdk-datasync", "aws-sdk-robomaker", "aws-sdk-transfer", "aws-sdk-globalaccelerator", "aws-sdk-comprehendmedical", "aws-sdk-kinesisanalyticsv2", "aws-sdk-mediaconnect", "aws-sdk-fsx", "aws-sdk-securityhub", "aws-sdk-appmesh", "aws-sdk-licensemanager", "aws-sdk-kafka", "aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagementapi", "aws-sdk-apigatewayv2", "aws-sdk-docdb", "aws-sdk-backup", "aws-sdk-worklink", "aws-sdk-textract", "aws-sdk-transcribestreamingservice", "aws-sdk-managedblockchain", "aws-sdk-mediapackagevod", "aws-sdk-groundstation", "aws-sdk-iotthingsgraph", "aws-sdk-iotevents", "aws-sdk-ioteventsdata", "aws-sdk-personalize", "aws-sdk-personalizeevents", "aws-sdk-personalizeruntime", "aws-sdk-applicationinsights", "aws-sdk-servicequotas", "aws-sdk-ec2instanceconnect", "aws-sdk-eventbridge", "aws-sdk-lakeformation", "aws-sdk-forecastqueryservice", "aws-sdk-forecastservice", "aws-sdk-qldb", "aws-sdk-qldbsession", "aws-sdk-workmailmessageflow", "aws-sdk-codestarnotifications", "aws-sdk-savingsplans", "aws-sdk-sso", "aws-sdk-ssooidc", "aws-sdk-marketplacecatalog", "aws-sdk-dataexchange", "aws-sdk-sesv2", "aws-sdk-migrationhubconfig", "aws-sdk-connectparticipant", "aws-sdk-appconfig", "aws-sdk-iotsecuretunneling", "aws-sdk-wafv2", "aws-sdk-elasticinference", "aws-sdk-imagebuilder", "aws-sdk-schemas", "aws-sdk-accessanalyzer", "aws-sdk-augmentedairuntime", "aws-sdk-codeguruprofiler", "aws-sdk-codegurureviewer", "aws-sdk-computeoptimizer", "aws-sdk-frauddetector", "aws-sdk-kendra", "aws-sdk-networkmanager", "aws-sdk-outposts", "aws-sdk-ebs", "aws-sdk-kinesisvideosignalingchannels", "aws-sdk-detective", "aws-sdk-codestarconnections", "aws-sdk-synthetics", "aws-sdk-iotsitewise", "aws-sdk-macie2", "aws-sdk-codeartifact", "aws-sdk-honeycode", "aws-sdk-ivs", "aws-sdk-braket", "aws-sdk-identitystore", "aws-sdk-appflow", "aws-sdk-redshiftdataapiservice", "aws-sdk-ssoadmin", "aws-sdk-timestreamquery", "aws-sdk-timestreamwrite", "aws-sdk-s3outposts", "aws-sdk-gluedatabrew", "aws-sdk-appregistry", "aws-sdk-networkfirewall", "aws-sdk-mwaa", "aws-sdk-amplifybackend", "aws-sdk-appintegrationsservice", "aws-sdk-connectcontactlens", "aws-sdk-devopsguru", "aws-sdk-ecrpublic", "aws-sdk-lookoutforvision", "aws-sdk-profile", "aws-sdk-sagemakerfeaturestoreruntime", "aws-sdk-customerprofiles", "aws-sdk-auditmanager", "aws-sdk-emrcontainers", "aws-sdk-healthlake", "aws-sdk-sagemakeredgemanager", "aws-sdk-greengrassv2", "aws-sdk-iotdeviceadvisor", "aws-sdk-iotfleethub", "aws-sdk-iotwireless", "aws-sdk-prometheusservice", "aws-sdk-locationservice", "aws-sdk-wellarchitected", "aws-sdk-lexmodelsv2", "aws-sdk-lexruntimev2", "aws-sigv2", "rspec-core", "rspec-expectations", "rspec-mocks", "hpricot", "ruby-web", "narf", "net-http-persistent", "net-http-digest_auth", "webrobots", "domain_name", "ntlm-http", "webrick", "tins", "sqlite3", "atomic", "english", "functional-ruby", "ref", "ZenTest", "logging", "os", "configuration", "mongrel", "tilt", "rack-protection", "backports", "mustermann", "hooks", "uber", "declarative", "declarative-option", "descendants_tracker", "axiom-types", "coercible", "equalizer", "gems", "google-apis-discovery_v1", "faraday-middleware", "httpauth", "google-cloud-env", "google-cloud-errors", "snappy-jars", "jamespath", "jmespath", "aws-partitions", "aws-eventstream", "http-2"]
Looking up gems ["net-scp", "Ascii85", "hashery", "spruz", "ParseTree", "sexp_processor", "diff-lcs", "polyglot", "treetop", "gherkin", "multi_test", "cucumber-core", "gherkin3", "cucumber-wire", "event-bus", "cucumber-expressions", "cucumber-formatter-dots", "cucumber-gherkin", "cucumber-html-formatter", "cucumber-cucumber-expressions", "cucumber-messages", "sys-uname", "cucumber-create-meta", "libv8", "safe_yaml", "needle", "jruby-pageant", "bcrypt_pbkdf", "rbnacl", "rbnacl-libsodium", "activerecord", "database_cleaner-core", "erubis", "daemons", "rspec-support", "connection_pool", "unf", "sync", "ice_nine", "tool", "flexmock", "lockfile", "little-plugger", "cgi_multipart_eof_fix", "fastthread", "gem_plugin", "rash", "escape_utils", "adamantium"]
Looking up gems ["blankslate", "trollop", "c21e", "SexpProcessor", "facets", "cucumber-tag_expressions", "cucumber-tag-expressions", "psych", "google-protobuf", "protobuf-cucumber", "abstract", "unf_ext", "activemodel", "arel", "activerecord-deprecated_finders", "memoizable"]
Looking up gems ["curses", "middleware", "bcrypt-ruby", "jar-dependencies"]
Looking up gems ["bcrypt", "ruby-maven"]
Looking up gems ["maven-tools", "ruby-maven-libs"]
Double checking for ["bundler"] in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally
Fetching gem metadata from https://gems.ruby-china.com/
Looking up gems ["bundler"]
Resolving dependencies........................................................................................................................................................................
```

what exactly Resolving dependencies do? why the Resolving dependencies running for hours? how to known the progress of Resolving dependencies?  what should I do to fix it?

[image]

this is my Gemfile(I have changed the source to china because the GFW but still not work):

```
source "https://gems.ruby-china.com"

gem "xcode-install"
gem "fastlane"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

when I interrupt the install:

```
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^C
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:158:in `block in trap'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:158:in `block in trap'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:504:in `=='
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:504:in `=='
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:504:in `include?'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:504:in `block in filter_possibilities_for_parent_unwind'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:503:in `reject!'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:503:in `filter_possibilities_for_parent_unwind'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:445:in `filter_possibilities_after_unwind'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:303:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/resolver.rb:50:in `start'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:273:in `resolve'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `specs'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:163:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:306:in `resolve_if_needed'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in `block in lock'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `lock'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `run'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/installer.rb:24:in `install'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:64:in `run'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:262:in `block in install'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/settings.rb:115:in `temporary'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:261:in `install'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/libexec/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/libexec/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/dolphin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

(base)
```

seems blocked for some reason.

Comment: Try specifying versions for some of the gems in your gemfile, especially those that use old versions in either the gemfile or the lockfile. If version ranges are already specified restrict them further.

Comment: I pasted the gemfile, and I did not know how to specify the version, I am a newie with ruby. I just using fastlane, and flastlane write using ruby @D.SM

Comment: Delete gemfile.lock and run bundle install, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Delete gemfile.lock and run bundle install, it will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33463877)